# Operand data type time is invalid for add operator

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, timespan

I have the following table:

```
                  SHIFT
 ----------------------------------------
| SHIFT_ID | SHIFT_TIME | SHIFT_DURATION |
| -------------------------------------- |
| 1        | 00:00:00   | 01:00:00       |
| 2        | 01:00:00   | 01:00:00       |
| 3        | 02:00:00   | 01:00:00       |
 ----------------------------------------
```

Here, **SHIFT_TIME** and **SHIFT_DURATION** are of type `TimeSpan`.

Now, when I run the following query:

```
var query = from c in SHIFT
            where c.SHIFT_TIME + c.SHIFT_DURATION >=
            new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour,
                         DateTime.Now.Minute,
                         DateTime.Now.Second)
            select c;
```

I get the following error: `Operand data type time is invalid for add operator.`

Why does it do that? How can I circumvent this error?

**Edit**: I have tried using both `.Add()` and `.CompareTo()` to no avail.

Comment: Have you tried using the timespan add method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.add.aspx

Comment: Yes, but it also throws the same exception.

Comment: How are you using TimeSpan.Add?  It should be like `c.SHIFT_TIME.Add(c.SHIFT_DURATION)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few problems I see.

**Let's start here:**

```
new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second)
```

Calling `DateTime.Now` multiple times is never a good idea.  You're reading the system clock three times.  Also, there is already a property for this exact purpose, so you can just do:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
```

**Next problem:**

```
c.SHIFT_TIME + c.SHIFT_DURATION
```

If the shift time is 11:00 PM, and the duration is 2 hours,  You might be expecting 1:00 AM, but instead you're going to get 25 hours.  (Actually you'll get "1 day and 1 hour".)  So when you it to the time of day (such as 12:30 AM), you're likely to be getting different results than you expect.

**Next problem:**

You failed to mention this, but it looks like you're actually using LINQ-to-Entities, as part of Entity Framework, attached to a SQL Server.  (I updated your tags.)  I can tell because the error message you are receiving is actually a SQL Server error message.  You can reproduce it in SQL Server Management Studio like this:

```
declare @t1 time, @t2 time
set @t1 = '1:00'
set @t2 = '1:00'
print @t1 + @t2
```

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Operand data type time is invalid for add operator.

While you can add two `TimeSpan` types in .Net, you cannot add two `time` types in SQL Server.  This is because `time` is meant to represent a time of day, while `TimeSpan` primarily represents a measured length of time.  (Technically, the `DateTime.TimeOfDay` property I mentioned above goes against the design purpose of the `TimeSpan` type, but it is permitted because there is no `Time` type in .Net.)

So when you were doing your original query, the columns of `time` types were added together, and this is not allowed.  The largest value of `time` type is `23:59:59.9999999`, so it wouldn't be possible to get the 25 hours result I mentioned earlier.

**What To Do?**

To manipulate dates and times while you're in the SQL query, you need to use the methods of the [`EntityFuntions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions_methods.aspx) or [`SqlFunctions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.aspx) classes.  These will translate to SQL's native functions in your query.

I believe this will do what you were looking for:

```
var query = from c in SHIFT
            where EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(c.SHIFT_TIME,
                    EntityFunctions.DiffMinutes(TimeSpan.Zero, c.SHIFT_DURATION))
                  >= DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay
            select c;
```

This will build a sql query similar to the following (assuming it is 1:00 right now):

```
SELECT * FROM SHIFT WHERE DATEADD(minute,
                                    DATEDIFF(minute, 0, SHIFT_DURATION),
                                    SHIFT_TIME
                                 ) >= '1:00'
```

SQL Server will implicitly cast the `time` input type to a `datetime` so it can be used with the `DATEADD` function.  It will also cast the results back to a `time` type, so you can compare it against the "now" time you provided to the query.

Comment: This is brilliant! Now it all makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: No problem.  Also, make sure you understand the impact of comparing time without a date.  When you go over midnight, it's like starting back at zero.  If this isn't what you had in mind, the you'll want to map that time to a particular date and use `datetime` comparison instead.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't know how to add two timespans.  From  [this site](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_sum_two_timespans) use TimeSpan.Add()

Then use [TimeSpan.Compare()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.compare.aspx)

---

are you doing

```
var query = from c in SHIFT
        where TimeSpan.Compare(c.SHIFT_TIME.Add(c.SHIFT_DURATION), 
                new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Hour,
                             DateTime.Now.Minute,
                             DateTime.Now.Second)).Equals(1)
        select c;
```

?

Comment: It is throwing the same exception.