# How to sum time(7) data types in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, datetime, timespan

How to sum two times data type in t-sql?

```
 declare @fTime time(7)='05:22';
 declare @tTime time(7)='06:00';
 declare @result time(7);
```

I used this but it doesn't work.

```
set  @result=sum(@fTime+@tTime);
```

Comment: times are points in time, not durations. you probably want them to mean durations, otherwise adding would be pointless? or add two times-of-day, but what about the carry when it wraps around?

Comment: @dlatikay yes, please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operand data type time is invalid for add operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578852/operand-data-type-time-is-invalid-for-add-operator)

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add the minutes of one to the other like so:

```
select dateadd(minute,datediff(minute,'00:00',@tTime),@fTime)
```

However, note that the comment by dlatikay is correct, `time(7)` is not meant for durations. It would be better to store durations as an integer, for example by storing minutes or seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use something like this?

```
DECLARE @fTime TIME(7) = '05:22';
DECLARE @tTime TIME(7) = '06:00';
DECLARE @result TIME(7);

SELECT @result = CAST([Hours] AS NVARCHAR) + ':' + CAST([Minutes] AS 
NVARCHAR)
FROM (
SELECT cast(TotalTime AS INT) / 60 AS [Hours]
    ,CAST(TotalTime AS INT) % 60 AS [Minutes]
FROM (
    SELECT fTime + tTime AS TotalTime
    FROM (
        SELECT cast(SUBSTRING(cast(@ftime AS NVARCHAR), 1, 2) AS INT) * 60 + 
CAST(substring(cast(@ftime AS NVARCHAR), 4, 2) AS INT) AS fTime
            ,cast(SUBSTRING(cast(@tTime AS NVARCHAR), 1, 2) AS INT) * 60 + 
CAST(substring(cast(@tTime AS NVARCHAR), 4, 2) AS INT) AS tTime
        ) x
    ) y
) z

SELECT @result
```